# Problem with TypeScript TypeError and Microservices

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, microservices

Everyone!

I'm now learning some microservices principies and i have some doubt's about on error in my query_service when received a event

Commonly my app create a post and in this post the user can put some comments, but i don't know what's going on and i'm tryed everything to solve this on my query service, because it breaks when the user make a comment in a post

The output error is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined

my router code:

```
import { Response, Request, Router } from 'express';

const routes = Router();


interface IPost {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    comments: Comments[];
}

type Post = { [key: string]: IPost };
type Comments = { id: string, content: string };
interface IData {
    id: string;
    content: string;
    postId: string;

}

let posts: Post = {}

routes.get('/posts', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send(posts);
});

routes.post('/events', (req: Request, res: Response) => {

    try {
        const { type, data } = req.body;

        if (type === 'PostCreated') {
            const { id, title }: IPost = data;

            posts[id] = { id, title, comments: [] };
        }
        if (type === 'CommentCreated') {
            const { id, content, postId }: IData = data;
            posts[postId].comments.push({id, content});
        }
        console.log(posts)
        res.status(201).send({});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    
});

export default routes;
```

Everything else works fine.
anyone can help me on this issue?
repo of the project if you want to see the entire program: [Microservice API](https://github.com/Thiago18l/ts_microservices_app)

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when the `type` equals `CommentCreated`, but there is no post with the given `postId` yet. In such a case you should also create the post first (as you do for type `PostCreated`), e.g;

```
if (type === 'CommentCreated') {
    const {id, content, postId}: IData = data;
    if (!posts[postId]) {
        posts[postId] = {id:postId, comments: []};
    }
    posts[postId].comments.push({id, content});
}
```

Alternatively you could throw an error instead of creating the post if a comment were to be created for a non-existing post:

```
if (!posts[postId]) {
    throw new Error("...");
}
```

Comment: Hi, eol, thanks for your reply, but, i don't know the problem with my comments array ok? this is the entirely problem with it, i tried to use some tips you put above but i don't have success,  still crashing my query_service for the same problem (e.g)  i created a post and it looks like this: { '2888baff': { id: '2888baff', title: 'Post 2', comments: [] } }, but every time when i try to add a comment to this post i received the same TypeError...  you understand my point?

Comment: How does your request for adding a commemt look like? Does it contain a `postId` with value `2888baff`?